# Download a attachment from mail and save it using java

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

How to download and save a attachment from mail using java?

Comment: Needs more details. Have you connected to the IMAP or POP3 server? Did you get your hands on a http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/Multipart.html Multipart object?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here : http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html and scroll down to paragraph **Getting Attachments**

Comment: I already read that link.. I need complete program for downloading the attachment and save it too using java or javamail